# CMFCRibbonBar remove/hide QAT

Tags: c++, mfc, ribbon

Here's the thing - we have a C++ MFC Project including a ribbon. We managed to hide the Main Button. Now we want to do the same with the QAT because it won't be used - we have our own QAT category. Is this possible and how?

Comment: [See here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/207929ae-fcad-4a50-aa8f-4460c8a8a430/how-to-hide-the-qatquickaccesstoolbar) - it may mean that you can't ... which is annoying.

Comment: Yeah, I read that... I was hoping someone might have found a way :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it! I derived CMFCRibbonBar. I added a method delQAT() in which i call m_QAToolbar.RemoveAll(). In CMyAppMainFrame::OnCreate() I call this new method.

```
class CRibbonBar : public CMFCRibbonBar
{
public:
   void delQAT()
   {
      m_QAToolbar.RemoveAll(); //m_QAToolbar is a protected member of CMFCRibbon
   }
}
class CMyAppMainFrame(...)
{
   //...
protected:
   CRibbon m_wndRibbonBar;
   //...
public:
   void OnCreate()
   {
      //...
      m_wndRibbonBar.delQAT();
      //...
   }
}
```

Hope it'll help other people with the same problem :)

Comment: Have you got any idea for this one possibly?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717117/resizing-mfc-ribbon-category-button-bar

Comment: Haven't touched cpp since more than a year... I don't work at that company anymore but from what I remember I used the same wrapper shown above to replace the main button's default logo. So if you create a similar wrapper you should get access to the class' private/protected fields and methods and therefore be able to manipulate all its attributes :)

Comment: If you don't want to derive new class, you can put this into OnCreate() in mainfrm.cpp:
m_wndRibbonBar.GetQuickAccessToolbar()->RemoveAll();